# Couting the number of times a value comes?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml file and corresponding xsl file. I have a following code line which is repeated lot of times in a code. I need to find how many times the value for status is 0 ? How can i do this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to check this thread - seems very similar
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721963/xslt-counting-elements-with-a-given-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The XML document is in a default namespace**.

So, the solution must take this into account:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="http://www.plmxml.org/Schemas/PLMXMLSchema">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>


 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:value-of select="count(//x:UserValue[@title = 'status' and @value= '0'])"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

**the XPath expression whic returns the count of the specified nodes is evaluated and this count is output**:

2

**Do note**: XPath expressions that use the `//` pseudo-operator can be very slow, therefore if the structure of the XML document is well-known one should use an equivalent XPath expression that doesn't contain `//` .

**For example**, if I have correctly understood the structure of the provided document, this is such a better XPath expression:

```
count(/*/*/x:UserData/x:UserValue[@title = 'status' and @value= '0'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the xpath `count(//UserValue[@title = 'status' and @value = 0])`.

Comment: I have edited the question with the code and i am unable to do it . Can U please tell me solution for that code ?

Answer (score 2):

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <child1>
    <UserValue type="int" value="0" title="status"></UserValue>
    <UserValue type="int" value="0" title="status"></UserValue>
    <UserValue type="int" value="0" title="status"></UserValue>
    <UserValue type="int" value="0" title="status"></UserValue>
    <UserValue type="int" value="0" title="status"></UserValue>
    <UserValue type="int" value="0" title="status"></UserValue>
    <UserValue type="int" value="0" title="statusss"></UserValue>
  </child1>
  <child2>
    <UserValue type="int" value="0" title="status"></UserValue>
    <UserValue type="int" value="0" title="status"></UserValue>
    <UserValue type="int" value="0" title="status"></UserValue>
    <UserValue type="int" value="0" title="status"></UserValue>
    <UserValue type="int" value="0" title="status"></UserValue>
    <UserValue type="int" value="0" title="status"></UserValue>
    <UserValue type="int" value="0" title="status"></UserValue>
  </child2>
</root>
```

This will count the number of `UserValue` nodes in whole file which are having attribute `Value='0'` and attribute `title='status'`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns="http://www.plmxml.org/Schemas/PLMXMLSchema">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="count_nodes" select="count(//ns:UserValue[@value='0' and @title='status'])"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="count">
      <xsl:value-of select="$count_nodes"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Count>2</Count>
```

> EDITED as per Dimitre's comment on performance difference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns="http://www.plmxml.org/Schemas/PLMXMLSchema">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="count_nodes" select="count(/*/*/ns:UserData/ns:UserValue[@title = 'status' and @value= '0'])"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="count">
      <xsl:value-of select="$count_nodes"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have edited the question with the code and i am unable to do it . Can U please tell me solution for that code ?

Comment: @kanwarpal, that is because you are having namespace in your XML. With this namespace URL "http://www.plmxml.org/Schemas/PLMXMLSchema"

Comment: Edited now as per your XML. Please test now.