# Setting a variable that counts the number of items in a for-each loop in XSLT

Tags: xslt, foreach, count

I need to set a variable that is total number of "Line Items" in each order in the following `for-each` loop:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Customer/Order/Item">
</xsl:for-each>
```

For instance, if an order has:

```
1X SKI GLOVES $4.99

3X TACOS $5.99

2X SNOWBOARDS $6.99
```

Therefore the number of line items in this order is 3.

I would like the variable to output "3". I will use this variable in the `for-each` loop to divide another number... Basically I am looking for something that outputs the number of line items to a variable. It should probably look like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Customer/Order/Item">
<xsl:variable name="lineitemqty" select="# OF LINE ITEMS" />
<xsl:value-of select="$lineitemqty" /><xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>    
</xsl:for-each>
```

Where `$lineitemqty = 3` if the loop is processing the order above...

Comment: Could you please add an example input xml. If like to count the Itemes in an orders it would be something like `<xsl:variable name="lineitemqty" select="count(../Item)" />`,

Comment: Will the [count() function][1] work? 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721963/xslt-counting-elements-with-a-given-value

Comment: Thanks @hr_117 that worked! I just had to use <xsl:variable name="lineitems" select="count(../../Order/Item)" /> ...

Answer (score 1):

Because you are looping over all Item ( for all Order and for all Customer) and (as I understood) you like to know how many Items are belong to the current Order, this it what you are looking for.

```
<xsl:variable name="lineitemqty" select="count(../Item)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just use (outside of the loop):**

```
<xsl:variable name="lineitemqty" select="Customer/Order/Item"/>
```

**If you want to know this number inside the loop**, simply reference the (outer-level) variable `$lineitemqty`.

**Alternatively**, inside the loop you may use the function `last()`:

```
<xsl:variable name="lineitemqty" select="last()"/>
```