# XSLT counting elements with a matching value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a variation on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721963/xslt-counting-elements-with-a-given-value) question

Given the following input XML

```xml
<root>
  <zone name="zone1"/>
  <zone name="zone2"/>

  <device name="foo" zone="zone1"/>
  <device name="bar" zone="zone1"/>
</root>
```

I wish to count - in XSLT - how many devices are in any given zone.

With my limited knowledge I came up with:

```xml
...
<xsl:for-each select="zone">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="count(/root/device[@zone = @name]"/></td>
  </tr>
```

How do I make it clear in the above statement that I want to compare the attribute `zone` from the `<device>` element with the `name` attribute from the current `<zone>` element?

Or is there perhaps a better/clearer way in achieving my ultimate goal?

Comment: To answer your question as asked: you could have used `[@zone = current()/@name]`. But using a key is both more elegant and more efficient.

Comment: Agreed 100%. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be best to use XSLT's built-in [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key) mechanism for resolving cross-references:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="device-by-zone" match="device" use="@zone" />

<xsl:template match="root">
    <table>
        <xsl:for-each select="zone">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(key('device-by-zone', @name))"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </table>
</xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```